# Loop deleting top row

Tags: excel, loops, row

Ive been using this code to delete rows if there are blanks in columns L:S but unfortunately it keep deleting the top row even though it all contains data.

It copies the data fine but then at the very end deletes the row with all the data in it. Very odd.

Can someone please help?!

```
Sub CopyValuesAndDeleteRowsWithBlankKRColumns()
Dim pasteArea As Range
Dim iRow As Long

With Sheets("Create Form").Range("COPYTABLEC")
    Set pasteArea = Sheets("Sample Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
    pasteArea.Value = .Value
End With
With Intersect(pasteArea, Sheets("Sample Data").Range("L:S"))
    For iRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Rows(iRow)) Mod 8 = 0 Then .Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `To 1` to `To 2` and it will not even look at the first row.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why its doing it for a full row? Dont really want to over look it if Im honest. 

Can you explain the last section of code for me please?

For iRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Rows(iRow)) Mod 8 = 0 Then .Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: There's also an unqualified `Rows.Count` in the first `With`1 block.  Make sure to do this instead, assuming you want to count the rows in "Sample Data" sheet: `Set pasteArea = Sheets("Sample Data").Range("B" & Sheets("Sample Data").Rows.Count)...`

Comment: Ah thank you. I will have a look at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the To 1 to To 2 and it will not even look at the first row